# Here is my swift code for solving eight queens puzzle

Tags: swift, recursion, puzzle, n-queens

The eight queens puzzle is the problem of placing eight chess queens on an 8×8 chessboard so that no two queens threaten each other. Thus, a solution requires that no two queens share the same row, column, or diagonal. The eight queens puzzle is an example of the more general n-queens problem of placing n queens on an n×n chessboard, where solutions exist for all natural numbers n with the exception of n=2 or n=3.

However, is there anyone can help me solving this problem for endless looping during the recursing method?

ps: You can just copy/paste to playground and try it, thanks!

```
class ChessBoard {

    var limit: Int
    var queens = [Queen]()

    init(limit: Int) {
        self.limit = limit
    }

    // Check if (i,j) is a safe position for queen
    func isSafeForQueen(atRow row: Int, col: Int) -> Bool {

        for q in queens {
            // not in same row
            if q.row == row { return false }
            // not in same column
            if q.col == col { return false }
            // not in same diagol line
            if abs(q.row-row) == abs(q.col-col) { return false }
        }

        return true
    }

    // recursive method
    func dropQueen(atRow r: Int, c: Int) {

        // running into last row
        if r == limit {
            if queens.count < 8 {
                queens.removeLast()
                let q = queens.last!
                dropQueen(atRow: q.row, c: q.col+1)
            }
            output() // if success, log out the positions
            return
        }
        // running into last column of current row
        if c == limit {
            queens.removeLast()
            let q = queens.last!
            // if no position for queen at current row, then back to last row
            dropQueen(atRow: r-1, c: q.col+1)
        }
        // if this postion is safe for queen, then drop the queen and try next row; if not, try next spot
        if isSafeForQueen(atRow: r, col: c) {
            let q = Queen(row: r, col: c)
            queens.append(q)
            dropQueen(atRow: r+1, c: c)
        } else {
            dropQueen(atRow: r, c: c+1)
        }
    }

    func play() {
        dropQueen(atRow: 0, c: 0) // game will start at(0,0)
    }

    func output() -> String {
        var s = ""
        for q in queens {
            s += "(\(q.row),\(q.col))"
        }
        return s
    }
}

struct Queen {
    var row: Int
    var col: Int
}

// Tesing：
let b = ChessBoard(limit: 8)
//b.play()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are having trouble grasping the concept of recursion. Recursion doesn't mean *everything* becomes a recursive call. In function `dropQueen` you are using recursive calls as if they were gotos.

Especially this one:

```
dropQueen(atRow: r-1, c: q.col+1)
```

That's clearly an attempt to do backtracking. Make up your mind; either do backtracking or use recursion! In recursion, coming back on earlier decisions is a `return`. If necessary, return a boolean to let the caller know whether the recursive call found a solution (`return true`) or not (`return false`). You don't need that if you want your program to find *all* possible solutions, rather than just the first.

Another call that caught my attention:

```
dropQueen(atRow: r, c: c+1)
```

A recursive call is overkill here, and confusing; use a loop to scan through all possible columns. By the way, by making this change, you will find the whole second function parameter becoming redundant.

This leaves us just one recusive call; which is more than enough.

```
dropQueen(atRow: r+1, c: c)
```

As pointed out by vacawama, the second parameter `c: c` appears to be wrong. When you advance a row (`r+1`), why would you want to rule out everything to the *left* of the last queen you placed on the board?

If you want to do recursion, then think about what your recursive function is supposed to do. Typically you want it to place (8-*r*) more queens on a board occupied by *r* queens already. You are working row by row, so in your approach *r* is just the current row number. Think how you can express the solution to the problem for row *r* in terms of a solution for row *r*+1. Make a special exception for the last row; once *r* equals limit, the solution is trivial (zero queens need to be placed); you are done.

Oh, and please rename function `dropQueen`; that name is a clear indication you were working on this with the wrong mindset. By now, you should be able to come up with something more appropriate.

---

**EDIT:**
You have shown considerable effort in making this work, so I will share my solution with you. It uses your original code (as seen in your question), but with function `dropQueen` completely rewritten (and one parameter less). Notice how short and simple it is; this is typical for recursion.

```
func dropQueen(atRow r: Int) {
    if queens.count < limit {
        for col in 0...limit-1 {
            if isSafeForQueen(atRow: r, col: col) {
                let q = Queen(row: r, col: col)
                queens.append(q)
                dropQueen(atRow: r+1)
                if queens.count == limit {
                    return
                }
                queens.removeLast()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As a bonus, if you replace `return` by `println(output())`, then the program will print all 92 solutions. You can see this in action at:
http://swiftstub.com/923601919/

Comment: Thanks a lot. Before i saw your answer, i really don't have much experience for using recursion. apparently i overused recursion for convenience and put all the heavy work to the computer and hit the performance. so i changed the core part of code and it works. i will put my code as new comment. just out of curiosity, will make it run faster if i write like old way ? (e.g. in C, people use array[i]=j representing queen(i,j) instead of storing data in struct or class?) it takes lots of seconds.

Comment: Good to hear you made it work, but the fact that it's even more complex than the original code, is disturbing. Recursion is supposed to make things simpler; you are making it way to difficult for yourself! Please take a look at my code (see my edit above); the whole algorithm in one simple, compact, recursive function. And like I said earlier: _no_ backtracking in a recursive algorithm! As for the 'array' approach, yes, that _is_ slightly more efficient, because you don't have the overhead of repeatedly creating and disposing objects (the instances of struct `Queen`).

Comment: Learned from master! When I start coding, I just followed my instinct logics: The way to solve problems could be step1, step2...and it seems defined my coding style. Whenever things go wrong, then I try to fix it, which means adding more code. For most of time, making program run become priority rather than making code flexible and reusable. Every time I think the quote 'fewer lines of code are better' or 'simplicity..', I can't agree more and I don't know how can I get there from here. Maybe few code means more thinking.

Answer (score 0):

my changed code:

first of all, i make dropQueen() and takeQueen() for specific purpose:

```
func dropQueen(atRow r: Int, col: Int) {
    let q = Queen(row: r, col: col)
    queens.append(q)
}

func takeLastQueen() -> (Int, Int) {
    let q = queens.last
    if q != nil {
        queens.removeLast()
    }
    // return (-1,0) means it's time to stop the game
    return q != nil ? (q!.row, q!.col) : (-1,0)
}
```

then, use for loop for iterate each column at same row, and only use recursion for backtrack (Of course, i renamed the function called makeStep() and added "Done" check at first when row == limit)

```
func makeStep(atRow r: Int, fromCol: Int) {

    if r == limit {
        // When find a resolution, keep the result
        // But it won't stop
        output()
    } else if r < 0 {
        // Time to stop game
        // but why just 27 resolutions ?
        return
    }

    var isQueenAtCurrentRow = false

    for c in fromCol..<limit {
        if isSafeForQueen(atRow: r, col: c) {
            dropQueen(atRow: r, col: c)
            isQueenAtCurrentRow = true
            break
        }
    }

    // Only use recursion for backtrack
    if isQueenAtCurrentRow {
        // if queen is set, go to next row
        makeStep(atRow: r+1, fromCol: 0)
    } else {
        // if failed, go back to last row and try next spot
        let (r,c) = backTrackForNext()
        makeStep(atRow: r, fromCol: c)
    }
}
```

the backTrackForNext() function is for back to last row and locate the next spot of last queen. if the next spot is out of chessboard, then go back again

```
func backTrackForNext() -> (Int, Int) {
    // find last row
    var (r,c) = takeLastQueen()
    c++ // find next spot
    if c == limit {
        // if hit end of column, go back again
        backTrackForNext()
    }
    return (r,c)
}
```

once it find a result, it won't stop until i get 27 results in playground. I haven't figure out why is 27, but you guys are awesome for helping me out there.